# Codeigniter how to remove "`" in sub query

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter

I have a problem when I run sub-query in from clause.

Here is my code

```
$subquery = "select column1, column2 from table limit 10, 10"
$this->db->select(column1, false)->from("( $subquery ) as b");
$this->db->get();
```

I get database error "Undeclared variable: 10"
And print my query is:

```
select column1 from ((select column1, column2 from table limit 10, `10` ) as b)
```

How can I remove this character "`"

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use $this->db->_protect_identifiers=false; which will remove all backticks on this query.

So your query will be something like:

```
$subquery = "select column1, column2 from table limit 10, 10"
$this->db->_protect_identifiers=false;
$this->db->select(column1, false)->from("( $subquery ) as b");
$this->db->_protect_identifiers=true;   // You can make it true again here to avoid removing of backtickes in further code unnecessarily 
$this->db->get();
```

Comment: Thank for your help. I have tried it and it worked well.

Comment: @CodeWithCoffee It's giving error Cannot access protected property `CI_DB_mysqli_driver::$_protect_identifiers`

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
$subquery = "select column1, column2 from table limit 10, 10";
$this->db->query("Select column1 from (".$subquery.") as b" );
```